# PHP mysqli do while loop - Display Catagories that have 1 or more associated records

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm positive this is a simple task, but for some reason I just can't find a resource to help me with the JOIN I need to do for a site I'm writing.

I basically have a Category Table, and a Member table which contains a cat_id, corresponding to said Categories.

I currently have a do while loop running so it displays all Catagories in the table, however, I now only want to display Catagories from the Category Table, if there is a record in the Members table with a corresponding cat_id.  This will help me, when I dd a new Member, the Catagory will automatically appear on the site.

My current code is;

```
<?php                                       
$cat_sql="SELECT * FROM Categories ORDER BY Category";                  
$cat_query=mysqli_query ($conn, $cat_sql);                   
$cat_result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat_query);
?>

<?php do {  ?>

    <p> <a id="<?php echo ($cat_result['catagory']); ?>"</a>         
    echo $cat_result['category']; ?> </p>   

 <?php } while ($cat_result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat_query))  ?>
```

Any help is appreciated as I cannot find a resource online that has this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a join in your sql as follows

```
SELECT c.* FROM Categories as c
INNER JOIN Members as m on c.id=m.cat_id
ORDER BY c.Category
```

This assumes that Categories.id is a column that corresponds with Members.cat_id, INNER JOIN will only display results that are available in both tables.

Comment: Thanks - This works great, I knew it would be pretty simple.  
I had to add SELECT DISTINCT in order for it to only display each category once, but it's exactly what I'm after.
Thanks again!!  very much appreciated